# Error in loading component property (Swing GUI Forms)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

For no apparent reason all my Swing GUI forms using components linked to org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter started generating errors when trying to open the Design View:

**Error**
Error in loading component property: [JPanel]->filterTextField->converter.
Cannot load property type class org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter.
The property cannot be loaded.

Errors occurred in loading...

---

I'm currently using Netbeans 6.8. I opened my project in Netbeans 6.7.1 and all was fine but after a while the same thing happened. Looking at the .form and .java files and comparing it to previous backups, everything looks fine. Even my Netbeans tutorial project no longer works.

What can cause this. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

After further investigation this is taken from my IDE's log :

INFO: msg
org.openide.ErrorManager$AnnException: msg
at org.openide.ErrorManager$AnnException.findOrCreate(ErrorManager.java:867)
at org.openide.ErrorManager$DelegatingErrorManager.annotate(ErrorManager.java:650)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.annotateException(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:230)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.annotateException(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:240)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.getPropertyType(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:2362)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadProperty(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:2041)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadBindingProperties(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:2627)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:900)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:845)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:979)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:845)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadNonVisuals(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:695)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:529)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:290)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$3.run(FormEditor.java:339)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:287)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1355)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:317)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:272)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:337)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadForm(FormEditor.java:266)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditorSupport.loadForm(FormEditorSupport.java:306)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditorSupport$3.run(FormEditorSupport.java:457)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:125)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load class org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@738d08[org.jdesktop.beansbinding] and ModuleCL@167e3a5[javax.beans.binding] starting from SystemClassLoader[556 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:241)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:95)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1445)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:95)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.getClassFromString(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:5516)
at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.getPropertyType(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:2348)
... 27 more
msg
Error in loading component property: Other Components->mainPanel->jTextField1->converter
Cannot load property type class org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter.
The property cannot be loaded.

---

Can someone please help me with this issue. This is still not resolved and not being able to edit my Forms or loosing binding properties every time I need to edit a Form is a real pain and time consuming! Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I would conclude from this message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Will not load class org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@738d08[org.jdesktop.beansbinding] and ModuleCL@167e3a5[javax.beans.binding]

that the system is finding 2 class files that contain org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter. Rather than just picking one (and being wrong 50% of the time) it refuses to load either one.

Check your libraries to make sure you're not loading 2 libraries with overlapping functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that sometimes NetBeans will lose a binding to a JAR you might be using for Swing controls.  For instance, sometimes I include SwingX's JAR for their components and the JAR inclusion gets messed up with NetBeans.

Make sure you don't have any broken library references in:

`Project Properties -> Libraries -> Compile`

It will indicate which library might be missing, or broken.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Check that your org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter is correctly in the classpath, and/or in the palette of Netbeans.

I usually get this error when I open a panel containing custom beans without these components in my palette (after reinstalling Netbeans, for example).